# Logical Operators in C causing issue with my loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, logical-operators

I am making a game for an assignment where there are 2 players and each turn the player rolls 2 die. When I ask the player if they want to roll again everything goes south from there. I'm confused because even if I change my `rollAgain` character to `'n'` it still plays my loop where I want it to run only if `rollAgain` is `'y'` or `'Y'`. This is my first program in C, I have only programmed in Java previously. I feel like I must be checking the logical operators incorrectly in my while loop but idk what I'm doing wrong, I've looked over all the code several times now.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     // NULL constant, srand() & rand() functions
#include <time.h>       // access your computer’s clock time

// function prototype statements
int rollDice();
int calcPoints(int die1, int die2);
char checkOne(int die1, int die2);

int main()
{
    int p1Score = 0;
    int p2Score = 0;
    int turnTotal = 0;
    char rollAgain = 'Y';
    char rolled1 = 'N';
    int die1;
    int die2;

    printf("Welcome to the Pig Game. Each turn the player rolls two dice repeatedly until a single 1 is rolled or the player holds.\n\n");
    printf("If a single 1 is rolled all points are lost. If the player holds, all earned points are kept.\n");
    printf("If double 1's are rolled 25 points are earned, if any other doubles are rolled the value is doubled.\n");
    printf("Player 1 has an advantage because they get to go first, the youngest player gets to be Player 1.\n\n");
    printf("First player to 100 points wins, let the games begin!!!\n\n");

    do
    {
        //----------------------P1's turn starts----------------------------------------
        while ((rollAgain == 'Y' || rollAgain == 'y') && rolled1 == 'N')
        {
            die1 = rollDice(); //roll die 1
            die2 = rollDice(); //roll die 2

            printf("Player 1 rolls %d, and %d\n", die1, die2);
            rolled1 = checkOne(die1, die2); //check if turn ending 1 is rolled if they did the below while loop will not run and the current while loop will end.

            if(rolled1 == 'N') //if a single 1 wasn't rolled calculate total for the turn
            {
                turnTotal += calcPoints(die1, die2);

                printf("Player 1 your turn total so far is %d. Would you like to roll again?\n", turnTotal);
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf_s("%c", &rollAgain);
            }

        }

        //-------------------------P1's turn is now over---------------------------------
        if (rolled1 == 'Y')   //turnTotal isn't added to p1Score
        {
            printf("Sorry Player 1 your turn is over because you rolled a 1 on a single die :(\n");
            printf("Your total score is now: %d.\n", p1Score);
        }
        else //player1 must have held
        {
            printf("Congratulations on scoring %d point this turn Player 1!\n", turnTotal);
            p1Score += turnTotal;
            printf("Your total score is now: %d.\n", p1Score);
        }

        //reset variables to start p2s turn
        turnTotal = 0;
        rolled1 = 'N';
        rollAgain = 'Y';

        //----------------------P2's turn starts----------------------------------------
        while ((rollAgain == 'Y' || rollAgain == 'y') && rolled1 == 'N' && p1Score < 100) //player2's turn should not start if player 1 has already won the game so we must check p1's score as well
        {
            int die1 = rollDice(); //roll die 1
            int die2 = rollDice(); //roll die 2

            printf("Player 2 rolls %d, and %d\n", die1, die2);
            rolled1 = checkOne(die1, die2); //check if turn ending 1 is rolled if it was the below while loop will not run and the current while loop will end.

            if(rolled1 == 'N') //if a single 1 wasn't rolled calculate total for the turn
            {
                turnTotal += calcPoints(die1, die2);

                printf("Player 2 your turn total so far is %d. Would you like to roll again?\n", turnTotal);
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf_s("%c", &rollAgain);
            }

        }

        //-------------------------P2's turn is now over---------------------------------
        if (rolled1 == 'Y' && p1Score < 100)   //turnTotal isn't added to p1Score
        {
            printf("Sorry Player 2 your turn is over because you rolled a 1 on a single die :(\n");
            printf("Your total score is now: %d.\n", p2Score);
        }
        if (rolled1 == 'N' && p1Score < 100) //player2 must have held, use an if statement rather than else because we don't want this code to play if p1 has already won
        {
            printf("Congratulations on scoring %d point this turn Player 2!\n", turnTotal);
            p2Score += turnTotal;
            printf("Your total score is now: %d.\n", p2Score);
        }

        //reset variables for p1's turn
        turnTotal = 0;
        rolled1 = 'N';
        rollAgain = 'Y';

        //if either player's score is > 100 the game is now over so the game ending code will now play

    } while (p1Score < 100 && p2Score < 100);

    if (p1Score >= 100) //player 1 has won, congratulate them
        printf("Congratulations Player 1, you have won the game! Pat yourself on the back!\n");

    else //player 1 didn't win so player 2 must have won since there are no draws
        printf("Congratulations Player 2, you have won the game! You are awesome!\n");

    return 0; //end main
}

//function rollDice rolles the dice for the player using a random number between 1-6.
int rollDice()
{
    // seed the random number generator using the computers clock
    srand(time(0));

    //generate a random number between 1-6
    int num = (rand() % 6) + 1;

    return num;
}

//function calcPoints that calculates how many points the player earned.
int calcPoints(int die1, int die2)
{
    int points;

    if (die1 == die2) //check if doubles were rolled
    {
        //snake eyes = 25 points
        if (die1 == 1)
            points = 25;
        //regular doubles = the value on the dice *2
        else
            points = (die1 + die2) * 2;
    }
    else //doubled weren't rolled
        points = die1 + die2;

    return points;
}

//function checkOne that checks if the player rolled a single 1 during their turn.
char checkOne(int die1, int die2)
{
    if (die1 == 1 && die2 != 1)
        return 'Y';
    else if (die1 != 1 && die2 == 1)
        return 'Y';
    else
        return 'N';
}
```

The players turn is supposed to end if a single 1 is rolled.
I would really appreciate any help I'm not sure where I am going wrong. The code just has a mind of its own after it asks if I want to roll again.

```
Player 1 rolls 2, and 2
Player 1 your turn total so far is 8. Would you like to roll again?
y
Player 1 rolls 3, and 3
Player 1 your turn total so far is 20. Would you like to roll again?
Congratulations on scoring 20 point this turn Player 1!
Your total score is now: 20.
Player 2 rolls 3, and 3
Player 2 your turn total so far is 12. Would you like to roll again?
```

this is the output I get if I say yes to rolling again. At the end of this output it allows me to input if I want to roll again.

```
    Player 1 rolls 3, and 3
Player 1 your turn total so far is 12. Would you like to roll again?
n
Congratulations on scoring 12 point this turn Player 1!
Your total score is now: 12.
Player 2 rolls 1, and 1
Player 2 your turn total so far is 25. Would you like to roll again?
Congratulations on scoring 25 point this turn Player 2!
Your total score is now: 25.
Player 1 rolls 1, and 1
Player 1 your turn total so far is 25. Would you like to roll again?
```

this is the output I get if I say no to rolling again. At the end of this output it allows me to input if I want to roll again.

Comment: `if(rolled1 = 'N')` and `if(rolled1 = 'Y')` You should be using the `==` operator here

Comment: oops @RishikeshRaje I'm so used to java not compiling for errors like that. I fixed those bits and I'm still having the issue though

Comment: Paste the output directly here. Do not provide links to external tools for the same.

Comment: I tried pasting it here and couldn't figure out how to get it formatted correctly on StackOverflow thats why I put it on pastebin. How should I post the output so that is doesn't mess up the formatting?

Comment: You have an outside `do` loop (first line) which does not have a corresponding `while`. What is that used for, and what is the condition for the while. Please edit the code.

Comment: Sorry @RishikeshRaje I should have included player 2's code as well. I just edited it with all of main.

Comment: @Sauromayne - Not sure what the problem with the given output is. The code will repeat until one of the players has a score above 100. `while (p1Score < 100 && p2Score < 100);`

Comment: @RishikeshRaje When the output gets to the part where it asks player 2 if they want to roll again it doesn't let me say yes or no it just jumps to the code where player 2s turn is over this is why i think it must have something to do with the while loop checking rollAgain, rolled1, and p1Score. Im also confused why it doesn't let me input the response to rolling again

Comment: @Sauromayne - Without the entire program it is difficult to debug, but possibly you are facing issues with the `scanf_s("%c", &rollAgain)` So, you can add the line `fflush(stdin)` before each `scanf` to clear the buffer.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I updated the post to include the entire program, I didn't do that originally because I thought having a huge amount of code is frowned upon here. I tried the fflush suggestion and I am still having the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple classic issues in your code:

- `fflush(stdin);` has undefined behavior. Just remove this statement, it does not consume the pending input in `stdin`.
- `scanf_s("%c", &rollAgain);` will read the pending newline in the input stream. To skip it, you can just add a space in the format string and you must test if `scanf_s` succeeded to avoid undefined behavior at end of file:

  ```
  if (scanf_s(" %c", &rollAgain) != 1) {
      exit(1);   // unexpected end of file or some other error
  }
  ```
- You should not reinitialize the random number generator every time you roll a die, just once at the beginning of the program (move the `srand()` function call to the beginning of the `main` function, and pass it `clock()` that varies much more rapidly than `time(NULL)`):

  ```
  //function rollDice rolls the die for the player using a random number between 1-6.
  int rollDice() {
      //generate a random number between 1-6
     return (rand() % 6) + 1;
  }
  ```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, amazing what a single space can do.